# Python 3.7.6 fresh installation...can't use PIP

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I  installed Python 3.7.5 and later 3.7.6, the same story. I need to install `Pwin32`, `numpy`, but can't do it.
I keep getting the error below. Installing on a virtual machine, same OS win10 1806,  everything works fine.

```
   D:\AAA\Python\Scripts>pip

   *Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "d:\aaa\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
   "__main__", mod_spec)
   File "d:\aaa\python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
   exec(code, run_globals)
   File "D:\AAA\Python\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
   File "d:\aaa\python\lib\re.py", line 143, in <module>
   class RegexFlag(enum.IntFlag):
   AttributeError: module 'enum' has no attribute 'IntFlag'*
```

The OS is WIndows 10 version 1909
Any suggestion is much appreciated, I looked on the web, still have no clue why this is happening.
thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+%27enum%27+has+no+attribute+%27IntFlag%27

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're running the python version you think you are?
How are you running pip?

Did you follow the steps in [the official guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-pip-from-the-command-line)?

> If pip isn’t already installed, then first try to bootstrap it from
> the standard library:
>
> `python -m ensurepip --default-pip` If that still doesn’t allow you to
> run pip:
>
> Securely Download `get-pip.py`
>
> Run `python get-pip.py`. This will
> install or upgrade pip. Additionally, it will install setuptools and
> wheel if they’re not installed already.

Comment: python -m ensurepip --default-pip gives same error

Comment: same as well  with Python get-pip.py

Comment: D:\AAA\Python>python --version
Python 3.7.5

Comment: You downloaded `get-pip.py`, ran it, and got the same error?

Comment: yes, same error. Only happens on this PC. Doing the same on a VM, same python installation executable, works fine.